# External services generated Dynamic Apex has _set attribute which is rejected by target endpoint

Tags: visual-workflow, dynamic-apex, external-services

Trying to use External Services to process a list of Objects.

YAML JSON attribute looks like below,

```
            "FirstName": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "FirstName is the firstname to use for creating the account. @gotag: valid:\"required\""
            },
```

Generated corresponding Apex Wrapper class (Dynamic Apex) has below,

```
// [PROPERTY] FirstName
// FirstName is the firstname to use for creating the account. @gotag: valid:"required"
@AuraEnabled
global String FirstName {get; set{ this.FirstName = value; this.FirstName_set = true; }}
global Boolean FirstName_set {get; set;}
```

JSON body sent by flow has below,

```
{ "FirstName_set" : true, "FirstName" : "Test" }
```

Endpoint is throwing error as it does not expect 'FirstName_set' in the request body. I wonder why Salesforce is adding this attribute? Is there a way to remove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Send it to your own Apex REST service that acts as a middleware to remove it or write your own Apex wrapper that removes it.

Comment: @identigral Yeah, That's of course possible, but we're trying to use this no code solution which is great! trying to understand why it's doing this.

Comment: ...because (for reasons not related to this use case) they need to know if a particular field has been set and that's how they chose to implement it. There's no way around this other than above.

Comment: @identigral, please add your very useful comment as an answer. People ask exactly the same question again and apparently this is only discouraged when the duplicated question has an answer. This one has - but up to now only in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Send it to your own Apex REST service that acts as a middleware to remove it or write your own Apex wrapper that removes it

Comment: Have added this as a commity wiki for now - if @identigral adds an answer can remove it again.