# Salesforce External service generated Dynamic Apex classes has _set attribute which is rejected by target endpoint

Tags: apex, external-services, openapispecification

Facing the same issue as highlighted in [External services generated Dynamic Apex has _set attribute which is rejected by target endpoint](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412927/external-services-generated-dynamic-apex-has-set-attribute-which-is-rejected-by). i.e. the when I register an external service with an Open API spec, additional attributes "_set" are added to the dynamic apex generated which are rejected by the endpoint.